# Why axios doesn't wait for response when I use await with async modifier?

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios, request, async.js

I have async function that fetchs data from the server in Json format.But it doesn't wait for response
This is the function I'm talking about

```
async fetchFromServer (startRow,filter, sortBy, descending,rowsPerPage) {
                const response = await axios.get("${pageContext.request.contextPath}"+"/Admin/OrdersSorted",{
                    params: {
                        startRow: startRow,
                        filter:filter,
                        sortBy:sortBy,
                        descending:descending,
                        rowsPerPage:rowsPerPage
                    }
                })
               return response.data
            }
```

Here I'm invoking it

```
onRequest(props) {
                const {page, rowsPerPage, sortBy, descending} = props.pagination
                const filter = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(props.filter).filter(([_, v]) => !!v));
                this.loading = true
                // update rowsCount with appropriate value
                // get all rows if "All" (0) is selected
                // calculate starting row of data
                const startRow = (page - 1) * rowsPerPage
                // fetch data from "server"
                const returnedData =  this.fetchFromServer(startRow, filter, sortBy, descending, rowsPerPage)
                alert("returndata " + Array.isArray(returnedData))
                this.pagination.rowsNumber = returnedData.length
                alert("length " + returnedData.length)
                // clear out existing data and add new
                this.data.splice(0, this.data.length, ...returnedData)

                // don't forget to update local pagination object
                this.pagination.page = page
                this.pagination.rowsPerPage = rowsPerPage
                this.pagination.sortBy = sortBy
                this.pagination.descending = descending
                // ...and turn of loading indicator
                this.loading = false
            }
```

Comment: An async function returns a promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use async in onRequest function too.

like

```
async onRequest(props) {
                ...
                const returnedData = await this.fetchFromServer(startRow, filter, sortBy, descending, rowsPerPage)
                ...
            }
```